# Allowing null vairiable

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I'm working on a shortcode to display a custom post type, which mostly works. I don't control the feed this data is coming from, hence the need to split up the title based on delimiters. The problem I'm experiencing is that the variables first, second, third, and fourth can be null, and I don't know how to account for this in this context.

Any tips appreciated.

```
add_shortcode( 'parliament-posts', 'display_custom_post_type' );

    function display_custom_post_type(){
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'parl',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'pagination' => true,
            'posts_per_page' => '10',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $string = '';
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $query->have_posts() ){
            while( $query->have_posts() ){
                $query->the_post();
                $string .= '<div class="test-parl-article">';
                $string .= '<img class="test-parl-icon" src="/wp-content/uploads/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Photo of Joe Blogs">';
                $string .= '<div class="test-parl-article-meta">';
                
                $title = (get_the_title ());
                $str = preg_split('(\||\[|\]|=)', $title,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
                print_r($title);
                $first = $str[0];
                $second = $str[1];
                $third = $str[2];
                $fourth = $str[3];
                
                $string .= '<h3 class="test-parl-title"><div>' . $first . '</div></h3>';
                
                $string .= '<h5>' . $second . ' ' . $third . ' ' . $fourth . '</h5>';
                
                
                
                $string .= '</div>';
                $string .= '<div class="test-parl-date">' . get_the_date() . '</div>';
                $string .= '<div class="test-parl-link"><a href="' . get_permalink() . 'target="_blank" rel="noopener">View in context</a></div>';
                $string .= '</div>';
                $string .= '<article class="test-article-body">' . get_the_content() . '</article>';
            }
                $string .= '</div>';
                
        }
                
        
                $string .= '<div class="pagination">';
                $string .= '<div class="previous-page">' . previous_posts_link( 'Newer Posts' ) . '</div>';
                $string .= '<div class="next-page">' . next_posts_link( 'Older Posts', $query->max_num_pages ) . '</div>';
                $string .= '</div>';
        
        return $string;
    }
```

Comment: are you aware of the `explode` and `implode` functions? Your query loop is missing the cleanup call to `wp_reset_postdata` after the `while` loop, so any shortcodes that come after this will see the last post in the loop, not the post the shortcode is used on

Comment: @TomJNowell yep. Couldn't find a way to make explode use multiple delimiters, hence the use of preg. Aware of the reset post data, trying to get over this issue before I worry about that.

Comment: true but you get an array out of it which lets you then filter out the `null` values, and `implode` with a space delimeter to create your list. I don't think this question is necessarily a WordPress question though, anybody with general PHP knowledge could look at this

Comment: @TomJNowell No one could point me to a workable solution which would allow explode to deal with multiple delimiters, and without that using it is pointless.

Comment: but you already have an array named `$str`, you don't need `explode`, `implode` is a generic function that runs on an array and returns a string, it doesn't care how the array was created

Comment: @TomJNowell it doesn't matter if it's explode, implode, or preg; they're all valid solutions. I didn't ask a question about generating the array.

Comment: you misunderstand, you can use `implode` to take the array you already have, and turn it into a string, solving your `null` problem that you asked about